# Java Dynamic Web Project with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee

Currently to access my dynamic web project (running in a tomcat servlet container) I access the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/[Eclipse_Project_Name]
```

I have a couple questions about this:

1. Where is the configuration that
       is forcing the url to require the
       Eclipse project name? I don't see
       this in the web.xml.
2. Say I'd like
           to change the url used to access my
           project.  Maybe I want it to by at
           the root: localhost:8080/, or maybe
           a different directory structure
           altogether.  How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Where is the configuration that is forcing the URL to require the Eclipse project name? I don't see this in the web.xml.

When you create a *New Dynamic Web Project*, the first page of the wizard asks you for a **Project name** and in the third page, you can change the web module settings such as the **Context root** which defaults to the project name (the *context root* is the part of the URL you're talking about).

This information is not stored in the `web.xml`, it is stored in the `.settings` directory of the project (to be precise, in `org.eclipse.wst.common.component`) and will be added later to `/Servers/Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost-config/server.xml` in a `<Context>` element when you will **Add** the project to the Tomcat server.

> Say I'd like to change the url used to access my project. Maybe I want it to by at the root: localhost:8080/, or maybe a different directory structure altogether. How do I do this?

**Right-click** on your project then **Properties > Web Project Settings**. There you can change the context root. Then go to the **Server View**, **right-click** on the Tomcat server and select **Clean...** and you should get prompted to accept the modification of the server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

to change the context root in eclipse please follow the below procedure

Right click on Project-->Properties-->WebProject